# Python- User specified range with bigger number entered first

Tags: python, range

```
import random
x= int(input('Enter first integer: '))
y=int(input('Enter second integer: '))

for i in range(1,21):
        i+=1
        q=random.randint(x,y+1)
        if q % 2==0:
            print (str(q)+' is even')
        else:
            print(str(q)+' is odd.')
```

Is there and shortcuts for allowing user to enter bigger number first ?Or do I need to nest another if loop such as 'if x>y....'

Thanks

Comment: you could always check `if x > y: x,y = y,x`, it's probably best to enforce some structure to user input though.

Comment: Thanks, how could I do that without upsetting syntax module?

Comment: the body of the `if` block needs to be indented

Comment: you need to define the behavior what if i  as a user want to go from 9 to 1

Comment: you can also use `assert y > x, "Second integer must be larger than first integer!"` after the `input` lines.